# how to implement something like a VCS status/ignore program?

Tags: git, shell, find, status, ignore

in `$dir`, I want to get an overview of all files/dirs (recursively), but:

- exclude all files/dirs which are included in `$list` (assume $list is newline separated)
- only include the most-toplevel directories not included in `$list` instead of whole trees beneath them

I currently use:

`cd $dir && git init && echo "$list" > .gitignore && git status && rm -rf .git .gitignore`

this is simple and the 'untracked files' listing is what i need, but isn't really clean, as it does a bunch of unneeded filesystem i/o for the tmp git repository and ignore file.

I've also been pondering `find` with prune actions or something like `empty=$(mktemp -d) && rsync -nv --exclude-from=$list $dir/ $empty` but those wouldn't work the way i want them to.

how would you implement this? is there any existing shell/python/... tool that does just this? or can i somehow reuse the git code without actually making a temporary git repository (or another vcs tool?)?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance for the terse 1-liner format (it was easier to test this way)

```
for FILE in `find .`; do eval "case \"$FILE\" in "$list");;*)echo \"$FILE\";;esac";done
```

the format for list would be "./path/to/file|dir|dir/*|*allfilesmatchingthis*|*.git..."

replace the echo with whatever "status" type command fits